# asp.net core content root is wrong on OSX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, asp.net-core

I have recently upgraded my asp.net core site to csproj and when I publish for release and run it on OSX no matter where I run the binary from the content root is /Users/MYUSERNAME. I am running the binary from the OSX desktop so I would expect the content root to be relative to this location and it worked fine before.

The line below is in my program.cs class. Is there anything I need to change with new csproj and asp.net core 1.1 packages for this to work as before?

```
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue and I have now resolved it.

So it seems that when I double click the dotnet file this was happening but my current working directory was `~` (`/Users/Username`).

So what I needed to do was set my current working directory to the published folder before running it.

e.g in the Terminal.

```
cd ~/Desktop/publish/

./DotnetRunnableFile
```

Where the `publish` folder is where my published files are and `DotnetRunnableFile` is the equivalent to an .exe on windows.